# Как сделать видимыми оба Scrollbars при HorizontalScrollView, вложенном в ScrollView

Tags: android, android-scrollview, horizontalscrollview

В `Activity` хочу рассматривать картинку, значительно больше размера экрана.  Использую `HorizontalScrollView`, вложенный в `ScrollView`. Вот разметка:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:scrollbars="horizontal|vertical"
    android:fadeScrollbars="false">
    <HorizontalScrollView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:scrollbars="horizontal"
        android:scrollbarStyle="outsideOverlay"
        android:fadeScrollbars="false">
        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/main_image"
            android:background="@drawable/paporotnik"/>
    </HorizontalScrollView>
</ScrollView>
```

В итоге правый `Scrollbar`, отвечающий за вертикальную прокрутку, виден всегда, а нижний, отвечающий за горизонтальную прокрутку, - только когда догоню до низа картинки. То есть внутренний `Scrollbar` как бы приклеен к низу самой картинки.

Хотелось бы, чтобы нижний `Scrollbar` также был виден всегда, то есть как бы был приделан к низу окна, а не картинки. Как этого добиться?